# PyQtWebEngine on MSYS

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, msys2, qtwebengine

I'm trying to run a Python code on MSYS2 that imports PyQtWebEngine, but there isn't a pacman package with it. Some of my approaches until now:

- Find WebEngine pre-compiled for MSYS2 (there isn’t)
- Copy pip folders with PyQt and WebEngine from outside MSYS2 to inside (format not supported)
- Install WebEngine by pip inside MSYS2 (format not supported)
- Compile WebEngine inside MSYS2 (missing module: QtWebEngine ; need to compile qt from source, apparently)
- Install PyQt-builder package for MSYS2 (has nothing that i need)
- Create a python venv inside MSYS2 (same problem with formats)
- Install Qt from .exe (took too long and didn’t change the result)

If there is an easier way, let me know

Comment: I read somewhere that is not possible. I also try it, have you found any solution?

Comment: @ChrisP I didn't find any solution to this problem. Eventually, the pipeline that uses MSYS2 was changed to not use this library.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/8444

Comment: @ChrisP as far as I remember, the [package](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-qtwebkit) referenced in this issue doesn't contain the PyQtWebEngine library.